# Remove all whitespace after specific word

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to use regular expressions to remove all whitespaces after a specific word. The editor I am using is Notepad++ but am able to use Unix

In this case it is VALUES I'm able to highlight by running regex \VALUES but I am unsure how to remove whitespaces after this.

Comment: By "after", do you mean immediately after, or anywhere after?

Answer (score 8):

Using `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/VALUES[[:blank:]]*/VALUES/g' input >output
```

This will replace `VALUES` followed by any number of whitespace characters (space or tab) with `VALUES`, i.e. it will remove the whitespace.

If it's important that `VALUES` is matched as a complete word, i.e. that `whateverVALUES` is *not* matched, then insert a (beginning-of-)word boundary pattern before `VALUES`:

```
$ sed 's/[[:<:]]VALUES[[:blank:]]*/VALUES/g' input >output
```

I will leave that out for the remainder of this answer.

For a more complicated value of `VALUES`, it might be convenient to not have to type it twice:

```
$ sed 's/\(VALUES\)[[:blank:]]*/\1/g' input >output
```

This saves the `VALUES` pattern and reuses it in the replacement.

If the pattern `VALUES` is stored in the shell variable `$values`:

```
$ sed "s/\($values\)[[:blank:]]*/\1/g" input >output
```

This transfers more or less directly into the Vim editor:

```
:%s/\(VALUES\)[[:blank:]]*/\1/
```

---

As I've never used Notepad++, I can only guess how to use it.  One should apparently be able to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and enter a search/find and replace pattern.

The search pattern *may* be `(VALUES)[[:blank:]]*` while the replace pattern *may* be `$1`.  I have no way of testing this, sorry. If `[[:blank:]]` doesn't work, try with `[\t ]`.

Comment: This will replace the "VALUES" with "VALUES" even if there is not space after it, unnecessary replacement

Comment: @MhdWissamAl-Roujoulah It will indeed. And it is unnecessary. But the extra time taken to figure out whether to use `+` or `\+` in place for `*` is longer than the time taken to execute a few extra substitutions, and the end result will be identical.

Comment: Also it might catch words ending in VALUES (though LVALUES is the only one I can thing of off the top of my head).

Comment: @jamesqf Now that's a good point that I didn't think of! Come back in five minutes and I will have fixed that.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks, I learned something new.  Didn't know that there was a special beginning-of-word pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\s*` (GNU) or `[[:space:]]*` (portable) to catch tabs (and all other horizontal and vertical spacing characters) as well as spaces.

```
$ cat file
stuff and VALUES    <--tab
more VALUES   <--three spaces
VALUES      <--tab, three spaces, tab

$ sed 's/VALUES\s*/VALUES/' file
stuff and VALUES<--tab
more VALUES<--three spaces
VALUES<--tab, three spaces, tab
```

Comment: Note that since `\s` or `[[:space:]]` match on the CR character, that could corrupt MS-DOS line delimiters. See `[[:blank:]]` for _horizontal_ spacing characters only.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/VALUES \+/VALUES/'
```

Using `+` to match all spaces after `VALUES`

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ bring up the find and replace window

In the find box, enter `(VALUES)\s*` (this matches "VALUES" followed by any amount of whitespace)
In the replace box, enter `\1` (this insterts the first group (inside parenthesis `()`)

Ensure regular expressions are enabled

Click replace all to replace all instances of "VALUES[some whitespace]" with "VALUES"